# Trie implementation in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, trie

I would like to know if my implementation of a Trie data structure which supports addition, search and deletion of words is considered standard/optimal. More specifically, I have used a Hashmap in order to store the children as this gives constant look up as opposed to a vector. I would like to know if this is a good idea. Furthermore, I have no pointer to the parent node as I didn't seem to need it: is this acceptable?

I found that the correct way to implement delete was a bottom-up approach. As an aside, is it possible to do it top-down? As in start at the root then count how many complete words are encountered until the end of word_to_be_deleted is reached. Then delete from last word encountered to this word in a top-down manner.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Node {
    private:
        std::unordered_map<char, Node*> mchildren;
        bool is_complete_word;
        char mcontent;
    public:
        std::unordered_map<char, Node*> children() { return mchildren; }
        Node *find_child(char c);
        void complete() { is_complete_word = true; }
        void not_complete() { is_complete_word = false; }
        bool is_complete() { return is_complete_word; }
        void set_content(char c) { mcontent = c; }
        char content() { return mcontent; }
        void add_child(Node *n) { mchildren[n->content()] = n; }
        bool has_children() { return !mchildren.empty(); }
        Node() { 
            is_complete_word = false;
            mcontent = ' ';
        }
};

class Trie {
    private:
        Node *root;
    public:
        void add_word(std::string s);
        bool search_word(std::string s);
        void delete_word(std::string s);
        Trie();
};

Trie::Trie() {
    root = new Node();
}

bool delete_until(Node *node, std::string s, size_t level, size_t len) {
    if(node != NULL) {
        if( level == len) {
            if(node->is_complete()) {
                node->not_complete();
                if(!node->has_children()) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if(delete_until(node->find_child(s.at(level)), s, level + 1, len))
            {
                delete node->find_child(s.at(level));
                return ( !node->is_complete() && !node->has_children());
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
void Trie::delete_word(std::string s) {

    Node *rt = root;
    size_t len = s.size();
    if(len > 0) {
        delete_until(rt, s, 0, len);
    }
}



Node *Node::find_child(char c) {
    if(mchildren.find(c) != mchildren.end())
        return mchildren[c];
    return NULL;
}

void Trie::add_word(std::string s) {
    Node *current = root;
    if(s.length() == 0) {
        current->complete();
        return;
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        Node *child = current->find_child(s[i]);
        if(child != NULL) { 
            std::cout << "child != NULL" << " word = " << s << std::endl;
            current = child; }
        else if (child == NULL) {
            std::cout << "child = NULL" << " word = " << s << std::endl;
        Node *tmp = new Node();
        tmp->set_content(s[i]);
        current->add_child(tmp);
        current = tmp;
        }
        if(i == s.length() - 1)
            current->complete();
    }
}

bool Trie::search_word(std::string s)
{
    Node* current = root;

    while ( current != NULL )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ )
        {
            Node* tmp = current->find_child(s[i]);
            if ( tmp == NULL )
                return false;
            current = tmp;
        }

        if ( current->is_complete() )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    return false;
}

int main() {

    Trie *t = new Trie();
    t->add_word("tes");
    t->add_word("test");
    t->add_word("testy");
    t->add_word("Hello");

    if(t->search_word("Hello")) { std::cout << "found Hello" <<std::endl;}
    t->delete_word("Hello");
    if(!t->search_word("Hello")) { std::cout << "Hello gone" <<std::endl;}
    if(t->search_word("test")) { std::cout << "found test" <<std::endl;}
    t->delete_word("test");
    if(!t->search_word("test")) { std::cout << "test gone" <<std::endl;}
    if(t->search_word("testy")) { std::cout << "found testy" <<std::endl;}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First, you should let your IDE format the source code, so it has consistent appearance (such as space after `if`, closing braces on a line of their own, indentation of the line `Node *tmp` in `add_word`). This makes the code much easier to read and review.

Answer (score 4):

### Memory Management

You're using `new` to allocate memory in quite a few places, but I don't see any matching `delete` call to also free it.

### Don't pass complex objects by value

You're accepting `std::string` parameters by value. This will create a copy of them that simply wastes CPU cycles.

Using a `std::`(C++17)/`boost::`(pre C++17) `string_view` as parameter (can be passed by value as it's made up of just a non-unknowing pointer and a size) will allow you to easily pass in either a `std::string` or "sample text" or whatever part of some buffer.

### Use `const`

If you have a constant instance of your class, you can't use it as all your methods are declared to only operate on mutable instances, even those that don't change anything like `has_children()`.

Declare methods that don't change the state as `const`.

### Naming

All the `Trie` methods (`add_word`, `search_word`, `delete_word`) contain `word`. This is redundant and I would simply call them `add`, `search`, `delete`.

`search` is not the ideal verb as I would expect it to return a reference to something (i.e. an iterator). If the return is `bool`, `contains` would be a better name.

### Private classes

Your `Node` doesn't seem to be used from the outside, consider hiding it inside the `Trie` class.

### `std::unordered_map` with `char` as key

Yes, a hashtable has `O(1)` amortized search time, BUT your key is a char. For only 256 possible values for a char, using a constant-sized array is much simpler and with less overhead than an `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: I believe memory management could be extended/reworded to use rule of 0/3/5 instead, since it fits it better, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have some questions regarding your comments.

1) memory management - I am freeing the memory in the method delete_word()

2) Can you clarify on the use of const? Do you propose that I use this on objects that should not be changed? Or do you propose I change the code so that it can be used with constant classes?

3) The node class should be contained within trie?

Comment: Another question I have: I changed the add, search, delete methods so that string was passed by reference (e.g. add(std::string &s) ). Now I can't add words by calling:

t->add("test");

Instead I have to declare test in a separate variable and then pass that variable to the method. Why is that?

Comment: I've updated the answer with details

Answer (score 4):

All of @Djrcaus comments, i'll look at little bit more at the functions themselves, and issues with regard to modern c++

### Tests

The empty string is a special case, test adding, searching and removal. Test double add, and double remove. All of these are very common edge cases with most container structures you will want to test that. `assert()` in the tests, this way you won't miss a test failing.

### Modern C++

Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL` it's much clearer. In general I would probably prefer using `std::unique_ptr<Node>` rather than raw `Node` pointers. This does take care of dangling Node pointers, in most cases you could use references to `Node` as return or intermediate values without having to go to the raw `Node` pointers.

### `Node::delete_until`

The function signature takes 'len' as a parameter but len is never changed, removing it will make the function clearer by using `string.size()`.

### `Trie::delete_word`

See JUrcau's comments about function names, the `Node*` variable `rt` is superflous, just use root. I'm pretty sure there is a bug with the empty string not being removed, see testing ...

### `Node::find_child`

`find` returns an iterator to the found object, by doing another access to `mchildren` you are forcing a recalculation of the hash. Use store the return value of `find` and use it to return the node.

### `Trie::add_word`

`child` can either be `NULL` or not, there is no need for the `else if` just use `if`, the last `if` check to mark complete can be removed by moving the line `current->complete();` to the outside of the for loop, this would also obviate the need for the check on `size() == 0`.

### `Trie::search_word`

`if ( current->is_complete() )` towards the bottom of the function, if you just use `return current->is_complete()` you can get rid of the `if` statement there.

### `Node` class

`children()` returns the whole map by value, definitely return by reference probably `const &`. With regard to readibility it's hard to distinguish the setters in `not_complete()`, `complete()` and `is_complete()`, especially since you have, `set_content()` and `add_child()`. `set` is a good default prefix for a setter, and passing a boolean for bool setters rather than using a two version will come in handy further down, so use `set_complete(bool val)`

### General

In your code you are mixing the implementations of `Node` and `Trie` that is not very common, and makes things harder to read.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you intend to expand the code futher, you can compactify structures like `if - return - else return`.

In `delete_until`

```
            if(!node->has_children()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
```

can be replaced with

```
            return !node->has_children();
```

Similary in `Trie::search_word` you can shorten

```
    if ( current->is_complete() )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

to

```
    return current->is_complete();
```